# Reading object's properties from MongoDB via mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, undefined

i have basic thing to do, yet it doesn't work.
I have following mongoDB: (collection fruits):

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f4d0d1f4e31f73410733d8b"), "name" : "Banana", "cost" : 4, "stock" : 50, "__v" : 0 }    
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f4d0d1f4e31f73410733d8c"), "name" : "Pineapple", "cost" : 12, "stock" : 30, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f4d0d1f4e31f73410733d8d"), "name" : "Apple", "cost" : 2, "stock" : 100, "__v" : 0 }
```

,and following code:

```
let scheme = new mongoose.Schema({});
let ovoce = mongoose.model("Fruits",scheme);
```

So, it's easy to read. Just call ovoce.find() (which returns the correct array). However, when i try to pick name for each and display it, the console logs undefined:

```
ovoce.find({}, function(err,res){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {//the res contains the array with all the fruits
        res.forEach(function(fruit){
            console.log(fruit.name);
        });
    }
});
```

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong. Help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe element of array need be parse before console.log? Log whole `fruit` and see output (or/and upload here).

Comment: The array:
```
[
  {
    _id: 5f4d0d1f4e31f73410733d8b,
    name: 'Banana',
    cost: 4,
    stock: 50,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5f4d0d1f4e31f73410733d8c,
    name: 'Pineapple',
    cost: 12,
    stock: 30,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5f4d0d1f4e31f73410733d8d,
    name: 'Apple',
    cost: 2,
    stock: 100,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Comment: execute `console.log(fruit);` (not `console.log(fruit.name);`) and paste output here.

Comment: This is what the forEach function returns when i log only fruit
<code>
{
  _id: 5f4d0d1f4e31f73410733d8b,
  name: 'Banana',
  cost: 4,
  stock: 50,
  __v: 0
}
{
  _id: 5f4d0d1f4e31f73410733d8c,
  name: 'Pineapple',
  cost: 12,
  stock: 30,
  __v: 0
}
{
  _id: 5f4d0d1f4e31f73410733d8d,
  name: 'Apple',
  cost: 2,
  stock: 100,
  __v: 0
}
</code>

Comment: one more hint please `console.log(typeof fruit);`. If it return `object` it's no way you have `undefined` from `console.log(fruit.name);`. If it return `string`, you need `JSON.parse(fruit)`

Comment: typeof fruit returns object.
Just for fun on literally the next line i logged fruit.name and undefined logged

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, i figured it out. I forgot to put `;` at the ond of the code. For some reason the program stopped in last callback function.